# how do i connect my function checkKeyPressed to change the colour of my text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

im trying to use my keyboard so when i press 1 its changes the colour of my text. ive added the keyboard function so when i press 1 it is recognised, its connecting it to the text which im struggling with. i have a feeling i need to add a keyListener but ive tried this and it didnt seem to work. any suggestions? thanks guys

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
 
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "49") {
        alert("The '1' key is pressed.");
        
    }
}




window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSomething, false);
 
function moveSomething(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
        alert("The 'left arrow key' is pressed")
            // left key pressed
            break;
        case 38:
            // up key pressed
            alert("The 'up arrow key' is pressed")
            break;
        case 39:
        alert("The 'right arrow key' is pressed")
            // right key pressed
            break;
        case 40:
        alert("The 'down arrow key' is pressed")
            // down key pressed
            break;  
    }   
}


document.onkeydown = keydown; 

function keydown (evt) { 

    if (!evt) evt = event; 

    if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.altKey && evt.keyCode === 115) {

        alert("CTRL+ALT+F4"); 

    } else if (evt.shiftKey && evt.keyCode === 9) { 

        alert("Shift+TAB");

    } 

}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>

</h1>

</head>
<body>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript String fontcolor() Method</title>
   </head>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item keyShift">1</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowDown">2</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowUp">3</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowLeft">4</div>
  <div class="item keyArrowRight">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you're looking for something like this:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", checkKeyPressed, false);
 
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == "49") {
        alert("The '1' key is pressed.");
            document.getElementsByClassName('one')[0].style.color="red";  //replace with whatever color you would like
        
    }
    if (e.keyCode == "50") {
        alert("The '2' key is pressed.");
            document.getElementsByClassName('two')[0].style.color="red"; //replace with whatever color you would like
        
    }
     // do the same for the rest of the numbers
}




window.addEventListener("keydown", moveSomething, false);
 
function moveSomething(e) {
    switch(e.keyCode) {
        case 37:
        alert("The 'left arrow key' is pressed")
            // left key pressed
            break;
        case 38:
            // up key pressed
            alert("The 'up arrow key' is pressed")
            break;
        case 39:
        alert("The 'right arrow key' is pressed")
            // right key pressed
            break;
        case 40:
        alert("The 'down arrow key' is pressed")
            // down key pressed
            break;  
    }   
}


document.onkeydown = keydown; 

function keydown (evt) { 

    if (!evt) evt = event; 

    if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.altKey && evt.keyCode === 115) {

        alert("CTRL+ALT+F4"); 

    } else if (evt.shiftKey && evt.keyCode === 9) { 

        alert("Shift+TAB");

    } 

}
```

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
}

.grid-container > div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<h1>

</h1>

</head>
<body>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>JavaScript String fontcolor() Method</title>
   </head>


<div class="grid-container">
  <div class="item one keyShift">1</div>
  <div class="item two keyArrowDown">2</div>
  <div class="item three keyArrowUp">3</div>
  <div class="item four keyArrowLeft">4</div>
  <div class="item five keyArrowRight">5</div>
  <div class="item six">6</div>
  <div class="item seven">7</div>
  <div class="item eight">8</div>
  <div class="item nine">9</div>
</div>

</body>
```

You need the `[0]` because the method returns all the elements with that class name (even if there is only one, there will still be an array of HTML elements.)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! been confusing myself not realising it was as simple as that!

Answer (score 0):

It's easier than you might think.
First we need to select your element which can be done using the id, class or even tag name:

```
const myElement = document.getElementsByClassName('keyShift')[0]
```

Notice the [0] at the end of the line there; because `getElementsByClassName` returns an array of all elements with the specified class name, you need to tell it which one you want. If there is only one element with that class in your DOM, you can select the first, and only, index of that array.

Now for changing the color, it's as easy as:

```
myElement.style.color = 'red'
```

You can replace `red` with your desired value and that's it!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @libbywinfield Would you accept my answer if it solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

The other two answers beat me to it, but for the sake of more examples:

```js
// color map, for example purposes
const colorMap = {
  49: 'white',
  50: 'pink',
  51: 'orange',
  52: 'yellow',
  53: 'blue',
}

// track keypress, since it covers up/down
function checkKeyPressed(e) {
    // attemp to grab the color from the existing map. If its not there, this will be null
    const color = colorMap[e.keyCode];

    // if color is mapped, 
    if (color) {
      document
        .querySelector('.color-container')
        .style
        // if you're using CSS variables...
        .setProperty('color', `var(--${color})`)
        // or, if you don't want to use variables...
        // .setProperty('color', INSERT_YOUR_COLOR_HEX_HERE)
    }
}

window.addEventListener("keypress", checkKeyPressed, false);
```

The key logic is in the `if` loop, basically you grab the DOM element you want to change, access its 'style' property, and change the color to whatever you want. Keeping a color-map object makes it easier to track which colors you want enabled.

[Plunkr Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/vsXtSkeA7fHCjQngzdA2?p=preview)

Comment: Perfect! exactly what im looking for! thank you so much foor your help